# Using yyyy/MM/dd simpledateformat can pass non-date String to Date

Tags: java, date, datetime

I'm using this SimpleDateFormat yyyy/MM/dd to pass a date value from String to Date. But there is this issue: when I input a non-date value, like 2020/12/2x, it will return to 2020/12/02. And when I try 2020/12/x2, the function will return an error. Anyone know why this is happening? Thank you so much.
Here is my code.

Declare SimpleDateFormat

```
    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    df2.setLenient(false);
```

Function I used to check if the string I input is a valid date or not

```
    private static Boolean validDate(DateFormat df, String s) {
    Boolean valid=false;
    try {
        Date d= df.parse(s);
        valid=true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
         valid=false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

I used input:

2020/12/2x

Answer (score 2):

The `SimpleDateFormat` class contains many corner cases with unexpected behavior (as pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433861/using-yyyy-mm-dd-simpledateformat-can-pass-non-date-string-to-date/65433922#comment115684972_65433922) the [`DateFormat.parse(String)` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) says *the method may not use the entire text of the given string*), and has long been deprecated in favor of classes in the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package. For example,

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse("2020/12/2x", formatter);
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

Is consistent, and throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020/12/2x' could not be parsed at index 8`

Comment: Answer will be better if you also explain what's actually going wrong with the old API, which is actually well-documented in the javadoc of [`DateFormat::parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-): *"The method may not use the entire text of the given string"*. Yeah, it's one of the many flaws of the old API.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `parse(string)` method just travel from index zero to the farthest possible index where it can parse the source string to a correct date and does not care about remaining characters. It makes result of

> df2.parse("2020/12/2x")

equivalent to result of

> df2.parse("2020/12/2xxxxxxx_anything_goes_here")

In case of `df2.parse("2020/12/x2")`. When the method travels to `x` character, it realize that there is no date satisfying "2020/12/x", so it immediately throws an exception.